# Matrix specification for simple diagram, using 'diagram' package

Tags: r, graph, diagram

I'm experiencing issues in correctly specifying a positions matrix for `plotmat()` from `diagram` package (technically, that's for different package (`plspm`), which uses `plotmat()` internally and allows to pass arguments to it). The diagram I'm trying to encode represents very simple graph, but I don't have experience working with graphs and, consequently, with their specification via matrix notation. Thank you for attention.

```
  A 
   \
    \
  B--D
    /
   /
  C
```

Here's what I've tried (among other attempts):

```
mat <- matrix(c(1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 2), ncol = 2)
plot.plspm(..., pos = mat)
```

P.S. Also would appreciate, if you could advise on how to control vertical positioning of elements A and C (distance from the B-D line), using `plotmat()`.

UPDATE (for @jbaums):

[image]

Comment: Maybe something like `M <- rbind(A=c(0, 0, 0, 0), B=c(0, 0, 0, 0), D=c('', '', 0, ''), C=c(0, 0, 0, 0)); plotmat(M, pos = c(1, 2, 1), name = c("A", "B", "D", "C"), curve=0, arr.width=0)`?

Comment: @jbaums: Thank you for your help! I updated my question with the result of running your code - it's much better than the one from my code above, but worse than the diagram, produced by `plspm` by default.

Answer (score 3):

Finally, I have figured it out myself. It's a little tricky, but not a rocket science. Thanks to everyone who tried to help or, at least, read the question. Actually, after I've figured this out, I took another look at the @jbaums' suggestion above and realized that it is basically the same, discounting non-essential details. The suggested solution (which was appearing incorrectly, as shown above) was tested in my `RStudio`, whereas, since my machine with `RStudio Server` was down, I had to test my solution on `R-Fiddle`... The same company. Same (similar) technology. Go figure. Anyway, here is my obligatory *minimal reproducible example (MRE)*:

```
library(diagram)

connect <- c(0,0,0,0,
             0,0,0,0,
             1,1,0,1,
             0,0,0,0)

M <- matrix(nrow=4, ncol=4, byrow=TRUE, data=connect)
p <- plotmat(M, pos=c(1, 2, 1), name='', box.col="lightblue", curve=0)
```

**MRE result:**

[image]